# Xbox 360 slim power supply unit issue

Tags: xbox-360

My Xbox 360 Slim's power supply unit got burned. The reason is that the input AC voltage (**100-127v**) is not supported in my country (here it's **240v**).

There were three electric shock sounds from inside the PSU (visible smokes also appeared) and immediately after that I disconnected the wire from my AC wall adapter.

What I want to know is, did my **System** also get fried along with the PSU? The PSU was plugged into my System when it got burnt. Please share your expertise ideas here.

**UPDATE:**

System didn't turn on (I didn't even touch it) just 3 poped electric noises from the PSU and my house's fuse is also went down. No lights or sounds came from the System.

**UPDATE 02:**

Bought a power supply from [eBay](http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=270740348485&ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT) that is compatible to my countries power difference

---

Input: AC 100 - 240V ~ 2A 47-63H

---

Output: DC 135W 12V---10.83A

---

Plugged it and voila..! Xbox did turned on and it's just working fine,except the power adapter sounds a little noisy (I guess this is because it's not the original and made in China).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking those adapters are of low quality and will most likely not invoke a fail-safe to save your device. I noticed the slim adapters are of a much lower quality then older adapters that had built in fans and a ground. Without a ground it had no where to send the electricity and more than likely it simply passed it on to the device.  The fact that you had to unplug it and it didn't shut down automatically is a REALLY bad sign. Generally devices can handle variances in voltage but in your case it was a significant variance. Did the xbox light up or did the touch button make the ding? If so your chances it survived are even less since it was obviously drawling power from the device. You probably have a very small chance it survived but the only way to know for sure is to test it this time not a on 240v outlet! Best of luck.

Comment: Odds are it is toast.  We can't be sure unless you test it, but given your description, it sounds bad.

Comment: I have updated my question.